# Problem pulling images when running private docker registry inside of Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I migrated our docker registry that was running on an external dedicated server into our Kubernetes cluster

Now I can still push and pull images to the registry from every external machine but when I try to deploy images from the registry to the Kubernetes cluster itself it is not able to pull it. I get the following error log:

```
 Warning  Failed                 47s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-kube-1-default-pool-c5e11d0f-zxm8  Failed to pull image "myregistry.example.com/appimage:1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry.example.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
 Warning  Failed                 47s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, gke-kube-1-default-pool-c5e11d0f-zxm8  Error: ErrImagePull
```

The registry is configured to be accessible via https://myregistry.example.com by a traefik ingress controller and it looks like Kubernetes is internally trying to take a different route?

Comment: Did you add `imagePullSecret` in your manifest file?

Comment: Why not just use the `ClusterIP` or internal K8S DNS to reach the registry ? In your current way, you are exiting the cluster and retuning back in. Kind of sounds like a longer path to take.

Comment: the `imagePullSecret` is ok, using the `ClusterIP` would be strange because the configuration would have to be different than on any other server or cluster pulling the same image

Comment: Which version of k8s? Did you solve this? I have exactly same issue running k8s 1.11.6 on Azure. Moreover, some times I succeed to create pod with image from my in-cluster registry, but some times not (for the same image). I monitored logs of the pod running my registry (`kubectl logs -n docker-registry docker-registry-5c6998f89f-hx96l -f`)
and found that it doesn't receive _any_ requests when `ImagePullBackOff` happens. Found this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/63874 which recommends upgrading to the latest k8s, will give it a try...

Comment: Also this seems to be relevant: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/failed-to-pull-image-from-private-repository-on-kubernetes-cluster

Comment: Actually we are experiencing the same issue on Azure with Kubernetes version 1.12.6. We also tried to scale up the docker and docker_auth services to all nodes (as suggested above in the digitalocean forum) but with no luck. Sometimes it is able to download the image and sometimes not. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: We moved our docker registry to Google Container Registry

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd path, but it should work, but taking a wild guess it looks like a [DNS issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611). (It works for me connecting to an externally facing service). Some things to look at:

- Can you resolve `myregistry.example.com` from any other running pod?
- What does the `/etc/resolv.conf` look like?
- What about your K8s nodes `/etc/resolv.conf`
- Can you resolve `myregistry.example.com` from your nodes?

Comment: It seems like it is not a DNS issue because it gets a connection timeout

Comment: Did you confirm?

Comment: I can resolve the registry form any running pod, the resolv.conf on the pod has `nameserver 10.31.240.10` in it, I can resolv the registry from the kube nodes, though the resolv.conf looks strange: `nameserver 169.254.169.254`